# What is the rate of convergence of $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(h)}{h}=1$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I am having trouble understanding the concept of finding the rate of convergence. My homework question is a more beefed-up version of the following: Find the rate of convergence for $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sin(h)}{h}=1$$ as $h$ approaches $0.$

The only reference I can get from the book is to use the Taylor series expansion of $\sin(h)$ around $x_0=0$ so that $\frac{\sin(h)}{h}$ simplifies to
$$1 - \dfrac{h^2}{6} + \dfrac{h^4}{120} - \dfrac{h^6}{5040} + \cdots.$$

Every other example of this sort that I see (ie when the problem involves trig functions) uses the series expansion. But then the series is arbitrarily cut off at a certain point! I'm not understanding
1) why the cut off point is chosen where it is and
2) how this affects the R.O.C.

So, to illustrate, the book might cut off the series and write it as
$$\dfrac{\sin(h)}{h} \approx 1 - \dfrac{h^2}{6} + \mathcal{O}(h^4).$$
Well, when written this way then sure: the R.O.C. is $\mathcal{O}(h^4).$ Why did they stop the series there? One could just as arbitrarily write out the series as
$$\dfrac{\sin(h)}{h} \approx 1 - \dfrac{h^2}{6} + \dfrac{h^4}{120} - \dfrac{h^6}{5040} + \mathcal{O}(h^8)$$
so that the R.O.C. is $\mathcal{O}(h^8).$

So what am I missing?

Additionally, here is the definition I am using to understand this:
Suppose that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} G(h)=0$ and $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} F(h)= L.$ If a positive constant $K$ exists with
$$|F(h)-L| \leq K|G(h)|, \text{ for sufficiently small }h,$$
then we write $F(h)= L + \mathcal{O}(G(h)).$

I guess I could ask at this point how the $G(h)$ is chosen but I think I intuitively see how it's chosen (at least I hope). How do we choose $K$ and verify this?

Any assistance with understanding the process behind all this would help. I've looked up many examples online and not of it is sticking with me. I'm hoping here that I can use the back-and-forth to understand it better.

Also, if you need any more info or context from me, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Well, $F(h)=\frac{\sin h}h$ and $L=1$, so $|F(h)-L|=\left|-\frac{h^2}6 + \frac{h^4}{120}-\frac{h^6}{5040}+\mathcal O(h^8)\right|$, which is still $\mathcal O(h^2)$ no matter how many terms you expand the series to. You take the largest term of the *difference* between the function and the limit.

Comment: @Rahul I think I'm starting to see it.

Comment: @Rahul I got it. I was able to get all the right answers on the rest of my assignment! Thank you! One questions though... Why the _largest_ term? If you go out further you find terms that converge faster. Isn't that what we want?...

Comment: @BarkJr. if other terms converge faster, then your error is determined by the largest terms, which will be the terms with the lowest exponents.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Okay, because it's the _slowest_ convergence that we're concerned about. So we use the lowest exponent here because we had $h \rightarrow 0.$ Assuming we had similar styled problems with $n \rightarrow \infty$ then I'm guessing we'd want the biggest exponents?...

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Actually, then it would probably be $\mathcal{O}(\dfrac{1}{n^k})$ and we would use the biggest $k$ value because that would still be the _lowest_ exponent (because $\dfrac{1}{n^k} = n^{-k}$), right?

Comment: If it converges as $n \to \infty$ then you're back in the situation that Raul laid out, so you'd still get the same order of convergence since you are still concerned with differences.

Answer (score 1):

Go the other way: the canonical way to express the most significant part of the difference is as

$$ -\frac{h^2}{6} + \mathcal{o}(h^2)$$

or even just $\mathcal{O}(h^2)$ depending on whether or not you care about the constant of proportionality.

(aside: I've not heard the phrase "rate of convergence" used in this context: I usually see it used in regards to sequences. It's probably worth checking your text to find *exactly* what they're asking for)

For practical applications, you take however many terms you need for your application: if you can solve your problem using just the fact that the difference is $\mathcal{O}(h^2)$, then you do. If you need $-h^2/6 + \mathcal{o}(h^2)$, then use that. Or $-h^2/6 + \mathcal{O}(h^3)$ or $-h^2/6 + \mathcal{O}(h^4)$ or $-h^2/6 + h^4/120 + \mathcal{o}(h^4)$ or whatever.

Comment: @Jurkyl You're right in that the context for R.O.C. is usually with sequences. My book has another definition regarding that. This particular definition that I prescribed here was the one used for these types of problems. Additionally (and I don't know why), the sequential version of R.O.C. seems to make more sense to me intuitively. I have no idea why.

Comment: @Jurkyl Also, when you suggest to "take however many terms you need for your application"... I don't know how many terms I need. That's actually part of my issue with not understanding this. But from the comments Rahul left above, I'm starting to see _which_ term I should use. I'm still not sure as to _why_ I choose such a term.

Comment: @Bark: Here's an example in a familiar case: if you want to compute $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x) / x$, then writing $\sin(x) = x + \mathcal{o}(x)$ is sufficiently precise to allow you to compute the limit. You know that's enough precision because you plug it in and compute and see that it works. If it hadn't worked (e.g. for this problem, if you had started with $\sin(x) = \mathcal{O}(x)$), then you'd compute more precision in the approximation and try again. After you do dozens of problems in this fashion, you might start developing an ability to *predict* how much precision you need.